# Angular - onFocus function not works on tag-input

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using tag-input, but I can't implement the `(onFocus)` function.

**HTML**

```
<div class="force-to-the-bottom">
      <tag-input [ngModel]="item" (onAdd)="onAdded($event)" 
       (focus)="focusFunction($event)" 
         (onRemove)="onItemRemoved($event)">  
      </tag-input>
    </div>
```

**Component**

```
onAdded($event: any) {
    console.log("Added Success");
  }

  focusFunction($event: any){
    console.log("Focused Success");
  }


  onItemRemoved($event: any) {
    console.log("Removed Success");
  }
```

The very strange thing is that onItemRemoved works properly, while focusFunction not fire.

This my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmidpt)

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ngx-chips [documentation](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips), the correct event binding for `tag-input` for focus events is `onFocus`, not `focus`.

```
onFocus - [?onFocus($event: string)]
```

> Event fired when the input is focused - will return current input
>   value

This is what you should be doing instead:

```
<div class="force-to-the-bottom">
  <tag-input [ngModel]="item" (onAdd)="onAdded($event)" 
   (onFocus)="focusFunction($event)" 
     (onRemove)="onItemRemoved($event)">  
  </tag-input>
</div>
```

I have fixed it on this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvrdlb?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: If you don't mind..I've one more question..How to using onFocus function if tag-input has value not null

Comment: @Pravu Hmmm, what do you mean by that? Are you trying to auto focus on the input if it has a value? Or..?

Comment: yup true... auto focus if it has a value..like my example on stackblitz